# "Invalid Postback or callback argument" on modifying the DropDownList on the client side

Tags: asp.net, security, drop-down-menu, invalid-postback

I know why it's happening and i turned the validation off on the page level, but is there a way to turn it off on the control level?

"Invalid Postback or callback argument . Event validation is enabled
using in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>in a
page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to
Postback or callback events originate from the server control that
originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the
ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
register the Postback or callback data for validation."

Answer (score 0):

look this post.

[Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-pages)

in this, i've used **Subclass ListBox** method. it works...