# Can I post-back <asp:HiddenField>'s value modified with JS

Tags: asp.net

As title, would this raise the same problem like [Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-usi) ?

Thank you

Comment: Might be better if you wrote out an actual question and gave an example of what you need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

No, no exception will be raised, you can safely post  with a value changed using JavaScript. I have personally used that approach to persist some important information across the postbacks. Example code:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
            document.getElementById("HiddenField").value = "This value is going to be persisted across the postbacks";
        });



<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx

> The page basically matches the
>   contents of the request with the
>   information in the __EVENTVALIDATION
>   field to verify that no extra input
>   field has been added on the client and
>   that value is selected on a list that
>   was already known on the server.

So this won't violate either of the rules.