# Modifying control with javascript - Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: asp.net, postback, databound-controls

I have a a dropdown on a page

```
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpName" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

and I on occasion want to add items to it using javascript/jquery.

When I select the items that have been added and it does a postback I get the following error:

**Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation. **

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this related post: [Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-usi)

Comment: yeah decided to put the dropdown in an updatepanel and insert the item from a sub...