# Invalid postback or callback argument error?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two dropdownlists and I am filling one based on the other using javascript. In my javascript code I am calling for a webservice and with the results returned I fill the other dropdownlist. The problem is that after I have done that successfully the following error started to occur:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to modify generated controls from client side, you have to disable eventvalidation or register all possible values with RegisterForEventValidation.
It's well explained [here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/22/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx).
It's because the data sent to the client and received after by the server differs.

edit:also responded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page).

Answer (score 3):

I got same Error when i got one of my clients project. It is related to the web.config file. Simply Paste the below code under appSettings in config file.

```
<add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
```

Comment: But this value is by default disable as per msdn document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the web.config in IIS

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages enableEventValidation="false"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when cancel event at end of grid event at server side.

```
protected void grdEducation_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  // do your processing ... 

  // at end     
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your respective control in the update panel it will resolve the issue.

`<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btnSearch" />`