# postback error in multiview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used multi view in my web site. I wanna insert news in this website in step 1 I insert short description and some other data when I want to go to step 2 I received this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

**code**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AdminNews.aspx.cs" ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="AdminNews" %>

        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="Vnew" runat="server">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                    <section class="panel text-center">
                            <header class=" label label-info icon-plus-sign text-center">
                                درج خبر جدید

                            </header>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <form role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="pull-right">نام:</label>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameNew" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control pull-right"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                            <br />
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="pull-right">تاریخ:</label>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateNew" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control pull-right" ></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                            <br />
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="pull-right">دسته خبر: </label>
                                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategoryNew" runat="server" CssClass=" form-control">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

                                    </div>
                                          <br />
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="">توضیحات کوتاه </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <textarea id="txtShortDEsNew" cols="20" rows="10" runat="server" class="form-control pull-right"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                         <label for="exampleInputFile" class="pull-Right">        یک تصویرانتخاب کنید.</label>

                                          <asp:FileUpload ID="fuNew" CssClass="" runat="server" />
                                    </div>    
                                </form> 
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server" Text="هیچ تصویری انتخاب نکرده اید." CssClass="fixWarning2"></asp:Label>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 "><div class="label-default"> </div></div>
                                        <div class="pull-right col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10">

                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 fixWarning2">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 fixWarning2">

                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 NewSocialnetTTl">تصویر: </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 NewSocialnetTTl"></div>

                                <div class="pull-right col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-sm-9">

                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="returnbtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning pull-left" OnClick="lbtnReturn_Click">بازگشت</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="SocialRegist" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-left MarginLeft20" OnClick="lbtnInsertStep1_Click">مرحله بعد</asp:LinkButton>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vnewStep2" runat="server">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                        توضیحات اصلی      
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewsMaxid" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center fixWarning2 MarginBotom15">برای آپلود فایل از این قسمت می توانید استفاده کنید</div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right text-center">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="pull-right">انتخاب فایل</asp:Label>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAboutUsInsertFiles" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-left" OnClick="btnInsertFiles_Click">ارسال</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuFilesTable" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSiteName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <asp:GridView ID="GVFilesTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="id" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GVProductsFiles_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="کد" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle">
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle" />
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#047269" BorderWidth="2px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Pic" HeaderText="عکس" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle">
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle" />
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#047269" CssClass="GVItemStyle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="حذف" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnProductDelletFile" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="حذف" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' CommandName="DeleteFile">حذف</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#047269" CssClass="GVItemStyle" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>


                        <textarea id="txtLongDEsNew" cols="20" rows="25" runat="server"></textarea>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblRegistWarning" runat="server" Text="متن شما با موفقیت ذخیره شد" CssClass="fixWarning2"></asp:Label>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margintop10px">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right text-center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAboutUsSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-right" OnClick="lbtnInserStep2_Click">ذخیره</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAboutUsReturn" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left btn btn-info" OnClick="lbtnReturn_Click">بازگشت</asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vEdith" runat="server">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                        ویرایش                                    

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center MarginBotom15">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="img_edith" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 NewSocialnetTTl">ویرایش تصویر: </div>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fUEdith" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 NewSocialnetTTl">نام: </div>
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameEdith" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control pull-right"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 NewSocialnetTTl">تاریخ </div>
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEdith" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control pull-right"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 NewSocialnetTTl">دسته بندی: </div>
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlCategoryEdith" runat="server" CssClass="form-control Myform-control">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 NewSocialnetTTl">توضیحات کوتاه: </div>
                                <div class="pull-right col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea id="txtShortDescribEdith" cols="20" rows="10" runat="server" class="form-control pull-right"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margintop10">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 pull-right"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right text-center">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="pull-right">انتخاب فایل</asp:Label>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton8" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-left" OnClick="lbtnSendFileInEdith_Click">ارسال</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FuProductEdithINNEr" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left" />
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margintop10">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GVproductFileinedith" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
                                        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="id" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GVproductFileinedith_RowCommand">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="کد" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle">
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle" />
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#047269" BorderWidth="2px" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ApicUrl" HeaderText="آدرس" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle">
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle" />
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#047269" CssClass="GVItemStyle" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="حذف" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProductBoxHeaderStyle">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnProductDelletFile" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="حذف" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' CommandName="DeleteFile">حذف</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#047269" CssClass="GVItemStyle" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margintop10">
                        <textarea id="txtLongDescribeEdit" cols="20" rows="20" runat="server"></textarea>
                              </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margintop10px">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right text-center">

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdithNews" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-right" OnClick="lbtnEdithNews_Click">ذخیره</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnReturn" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left btn btn-info" OnClick="lbtnReturn_Click">بازگشت</asp:LinkButton>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vDelet" runat="server">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                                        حذف                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader">
                                                آیا با حذف موافقید؟                                           


                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15">


                                                    <div class="pull-right col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 NewSocialnetTTl"></div>

                                                    <div class="pull-right col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">

                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning pull-left" OnClick="lbtnReturn_Click">بازگشت</asp:LinkButton>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-right MarginLeft20" OnClick="lbtnDelet_Click">حذف</asp:LinkButton>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="pull-right col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 NewSocialnetTTl"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vComment" runat="server">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 myheader text-center">


                          نظرات کاربران

                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblCommentWarning" runat="server" Text="در خواست شما با موفقیت انجام شد" CssClass="fixWarning" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 PaddingZiro">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-1 pull-right"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <%-- every comment start from here--%>
                        <asp:DataList ID="dlMessage" runat="server" OnItemCommand="dlMessage_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15 commentStyle">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 pull-right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 pull-right text-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right text-center">
                                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentLike" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cmlike") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right text-center">
                                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentDisLike" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("dislike") %>'></asp:Label>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 pull-right">

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCommentDelet" runat="server" CssClass=" btn btn-danger " data-toggle="tooltip" title="حذف" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>'>
                                         <i class=" icon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnMCommentBlock" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn default pull-left hlBlock" data-toggle="tooltip" title="غیر فعال کردن" CommandName="block"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>'>
                                                            <i class=" icon-ban-circle " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>

                                        <span class="pull-left spacerStyle">/</span>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCommentActive" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn default pull-left hlActive" data-toggle="tooltip" title="فعال کردن"  CommandName="active"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>'>
                                                            <i class=" icon-check " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15 text-justify">

                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentBody" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("commentBdy") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 MarginBotom15 text-justify">

                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 pull-right text-center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("commentdate") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 pull-right text-center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("time") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right text-center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentip" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ip") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right text-center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>

          </section>
              </section>
</asp:Content>
```

whats wrong ?

Comment: any solution for my problem?

Comment: your view is not inside an update panel right?

Comment: yes. i did not use update panel

Comment: why dont you try putting your view inside an update panel. Either 'Always' or 'Conditional' update mode could solve your problem

Comment: where should i write this ? because when i use this control asp did not recognize my fileuploader

Comment: oh, then use in such a way that only the content thst needs to bbe updated in inside an update panel. and dont link the button uploading your files to this update panel.

Comment: i cant understand what is wrong with my code i use this code a lot and have not any problem

Comment: why dont you try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443344/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-error