# Asp button is called by default postback method

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX code :

```
<asp:Button ID="medicalSub" runat="server" ValidationGroup="medical" Text="Save" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="medicalSub_Click" />
```

ASPX.CS code :

```
 protected void medicalSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            console.writeline("hello");
        }
```

Error

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help you. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443344/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-error/48534443) Regards,

Answer (score 0):

According to that stack trace, the problem is not calling the click method. Instead, it's failing trying to load viewstate for a dropdown list control. This is long before trying to handle any events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

copy and paste this in your page load section of your code and check if that helps:

```
If(!IsPostBack)
{


}
```

Or the following will hep:

```
<%@ Page so just add the rest => EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```