# ImageButton event giving Invalid Postback in GridView

Tags: gridview, postback, imagebutton, argumentexception

Gridview postback Issues:
After much time and frustration, I'm posting the solution for others struggling with the same scenario...

On pageLoad I was binding the gridview for an initial display of the data. One column had an imagebutton (templatefield). Clicking an ImageButton caused an the error: "Invalid Postback".

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote considering the activity on this topic... anyway, perhaps I was too brief. Here is a much better discussion on the same issue &resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause: I had inadvertently failed to put a (! IsPostback) condition in the pageload around the  bind. It was causing some sort of double bind when the ImageButton's click event fired; thus, creating a conflict.