# How to get GridView row index without triggering this exception?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, events, gridview

I am trying to obtain the row index on a button click in an asp gridview.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="true" ID="pnlGV">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTasks" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" DataKeyNames="TaskID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" SkinID="standard_gv" EmptyDataText="No tasks match your search terms">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="TaskID" DataField="TaskID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Task ID" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="ProjectCode" DataField="ProjectCode" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Project Code" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="TaskType" DataField="TaskType" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Task Type" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="TaskDescription" DataField="TaskDescription" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="BizArea" DataField="BizArea" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Business Area" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="TargetDate" DataField="TargetDate" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Target" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="TaskStatus" DataField="TaskStatus" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField SortExpression="TaskPriority" DataField="TaskPriority" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Priority" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnNotes" runat="server" CommandName="notes" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" Text="Notes" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

and

```
Protected Sub gvTasks_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Try
        If (e.CommandName = "notes") Then

            Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

            Dim row As GridViewRow = gvTasks.Rows(index)

            notesAcc.Populate(CInt(gvTasks.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text))

            notesAcc.Visible = True

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

This just throws this error message at me:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

and I have no idea how to fix it.

Would anyone be able to give me some insight?

Thank you in advance.

Tom

Edit:
Thank you for the responses, it is much appreciated.

What is notesAcc.Populate(CInt(gvTasks.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text)) dong? If you comment it out does the problem go away?

That is calling a Sub from an .ascx file, and I wouldn't imagine so as I've breakpointed the event handler and it doesn't even reach it.

Do you get that error when page loads or when you click the button?

When I click the button.

***It is probably worth mentioning that I am no longer getting the error. I made a tiny insignificant change - so small I can't even remember what it was - and it's gone away, however, it's still not working as intended. The event handler doesn't trigger and I have no idea why. Again, would anyone be able to give me a nudge in the right direction?***

Comment: You can check these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page

Comment: What is notesAcc.Populate(CInt(gvTasks.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text)) dong?    If you comment it out does the problem go away?

Comment: Do you get that error when page loads or when you click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of 3 things:

Set AutoEventWireUp to true.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Manager.Default" %>
```

or

Add the event to the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTasks" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" DataKeyNames="TaskID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" SkinID="standard_gv" EmptyDataText="No tasks match your search terms" OnRowCommand="gvTasks_RowCommand">
```

or

Add the handles keyword to the method

```
Protected Sub gvTasks_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvTasks.RowCommand
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had added "OnRowCommand="gvTasks_RowCommand" to the LinkButton and that hadn't worked, but it does for the GridView. 

If I had a high enough reputation I'd +1 it but I can't as I'm new.