# Textbox show/hide on button click and dropdown fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an functionality where on click of button a textbox should appear, and whatever the user fills the value , it should automatically gets updated in that dropdown. I tried with the below mentioned code, where I am hiding/showing the textbox but unable to fill the dropdown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOtherBusiness').hide();
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnbusinessAdd").click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOtherBusiness').show();
        });
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnbusinessAdd").click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOtherBusiness').hide();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Also see the html for dropdown, textbox and button :-

```
 <td>
     <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddlBusinessUnit" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:Button ID="btnbusinessAdd" runat="server" Width="63" Text="Add" CausesValidation="false"/>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherBusiness" runat="server" Visible="true" CssClass="txtfld-popup" CausesValidation="false"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqBusinessUnit" ControlToValidate="ddlBusinessUnit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter business unit" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for adding value and text to drop down

EDIT: edited the visibility condition

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtOtherBusiness').hide();
        $('#btnbusinessAdd').click(function () {
            if ($('#txtOtherBusiness').is(':visible')) {
                var text = $('#txtOtherBusiness').val();
                var dropDown = $('#ddlBusinessUnit');
                var text = $('#txtOtherBusiness').val();
                var itemVal = 1; // some value for option
                var newItem = $('<option/>').val(itemVal).text(text).appendTo(dropDown);
                $('#txtOtherBusiness').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#txtOtherBusiness').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Its not working, I want whenever a user click on add  button a textbox should be visible and whatever value he puts it should gets copied in the dropdown list.

Comment: you can set its visibility hidden by default, you are using asp.net so ids may differ i think, use appropriate ids

Comment: sorry i missed $ before ('<option/>'), now i edited, working example.... http://jsfiddle.net/Dasarp/oyLkLwd0/1/

Comment: One more thing, the textbox is not getting clear after adding. It still shows me the last value added in the textbox. How should I clear it.?

Comment: just use $('#txtOtherBusiness').val(''); after value added to dropdown

Comment: Did everything, when I submit my form with valid details it gave me this error "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Comment: I am not familiar with asp.net, following link will be useful to you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page

Comment: I think you did your job, will check it out why this is happening. Anyways, Thanks a lot. It helped.! :) Happy weekend

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use `.toggle()` in jquery

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnbusinessAdd").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOtherBusiness').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: the page is getting refreshed as I click on the button. why ?

Comment: Its working, how should I copy the data from that textbox to the mention dropdown ?