# Dynamically Created ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have Created List View Control In Custom Web Control

following are my All Template :

```
    private class LayoutHeaderTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div") { ID = "itemPlaceholder" };

            var headerTable = new HtmlGenericControl("table");

            headerTable.Attributes.Add("border", "1px");
            var headerTr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            var headerTd1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            headerTd1.Attributes.Add("width", "200");
            headerTd1.Controls.Add(new CheckBox() { Text = "None", ID = "CheckNoneId", CssClass="CheckNone" });
            var headerTd2 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            headerTd2.Attributes.Add("width", "100");
            var headerTd3 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            headerTd3.Attributes.Add("width", "100");
            headerTr.Controls.Add(headerTd1);
            headerTr.Controls.Add(headerTd2);
            headerTr.Controls.Add(headerTd3);
            headerTable.Controls.Add(headerTr);
            container.Controls.Add(headerTable);

            container.Controls.Add(div);

            var footerTable = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
            footerTable.Attributes.Add("class", "Footer");
            footerTable.Attributes.Add("border", "1px");
            var footerTr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            var footerTd1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            footerTd1.Attributes.Add("width", "200");
            CheckBox CheckOther = new CheckBox() { Text = "Other", ID = "CheckOtherId", CssClass = "CheckOther" };
            CheckOther.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return otherCheckBoxSelect(this);");
            footerTd1.Controls.Add(CheckOther);                
            var footerTd2 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            footerTd2.Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");
            footerTd2.Attributes.Add("width", "205");
            footerTd2.Controls.Add(new CheckBox() { Text = "Show Additional Info", ID = "CheckAdditionalInfoId",CssClass="AdditionalInfo" });
            footerTr.Controls.Add(footerTd1);
            footerTr.Controls.Add(footerTd2);                
            footerTable.Controls.Add(footerTr);
            container.Controls.Add(footerTable);

        }

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Created Item Template for List View.
    /// </summary>
    private class ItemTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            var tbl1 = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
            tbl1.Attributes.Add("border", "1px");
            var tr1 = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            var td1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            td1.Attributes.Add("width", "200");
            td1.DataBinding += DataBinding;
            var td2 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            td2.Attributes.Add("width", "100");
            td2.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Edit", ID = "EditButtonId", CausesValidation = false, CommandName = "Edit" });
            var td3 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            td3.Attributes.Add("width", "100");
            td3.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Delete", CausesValidation = false, CommandName = "Delete", OnClientClick = "return deleteConfirm();" });
            tr1.Controls.Add(td1);
            tr1.Controls.Add(td2);
            tr1.Controls.Add(td3);
            tbl1.Controls.Add(tr1);
            container.Controls.Add(tbl1);
        }

        public void DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var container = (HtmlGenericControl)sender;
            var dataItem = ((ListViewDataItem)container.NamingContainer).DataItem;
            container.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = dataItem.ToString(), ID = "ItemLabelId" });

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Created EditItemTemplate for List View.
    /// </summary>
    private class EditItemTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            var tbl1 = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
            tbl1.Attributes.Add("border", "1px");
            var tr1 = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            var td1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            td1.Attributes.Add("width", "200");
            td1.DataBinding += DataBinding;
            var td2 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            td2.Attributes.Add("width", "100");
            td2.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Update", ID = "UpdateButtonId", CausesValidation = false, CommandName = "Update" });
            var td3 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            td3.Attributes.Add("width", "100");
            td3.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Cancel", ID = "CancelButtonId", CausesValidation = false, CommandName = "Cancel" });
            tr1.Controls.Add(td1);
            tr1.Controls.Add(td2);
            tr1.Controls.Add(td3);
            tbl1.Controls.Add(tr1);
            container.Controls.Add(tbl1);
        }

        public void DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var container = (HtmlGenericControl)sender;
            var dataItem = ((ListViewDataItem)container.NamingContainer).DataItem;
            container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = dataItem.ToString(), ID = "ItemTextBoxID" });

        }
    }`
```

following are my all List View Events:

```
protected void itemValueListView_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)

        {
            itemValueListView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            this.itemValueListView.DataSource = this.ItemValueList;
            this.itemValueListView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void itemValueListView_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = itemValueListView.Items[e.ItemIndex];
            TextBox itemTextBox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("ItemTextBoxID");

            this.itemValueList.RemoveAt(e.ItemIndex);
            this.itemValueList.Insert(e.ItemIndex, itemTextBox.Text);

            itemValueListView.EditIndex = -1;
            this.itemValueListView.DataSource = this.ItemValueList;
            this.itemValueListView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void itemValueListView_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            itemValueListView.EditIndex = -1;

            this.itemValueListView.DataSource = this.ItemValueList;
            this.itemValueListView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void itemValueListView_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = itemValueListView.Items[e.ItemIndex];

            Label itemLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("ItemLabelId");
            this.itemValueList.Remove(itemLabel.Text);

            this.itemValueListView.DataSource = this.ItemValueList;
            this.itemValueListView.DataBind();
        }`
```

when i am Clicking on update ,Delete  button in ListView It is Giving Me error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +144
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +122
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

Please Help Me I am Not able to get what is the exact problem.

Comment: It may help if you nail down the problem and post shorter example where the problem is easy to reproduce.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turn off Event validation for it to work. But this isn't suggest as event validation is to prevent hacking. it checks that postbacks are not done by invisible controls or non-existent controls.

You should turn off event validation at the page level , then call RegisterForEventValidation for **all controls** on the page, to have their events and postback values validated.

`<pages enableEventValidation="false"/>`

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(button1.UniqueID);`

**Edit:**

You could also dynamically add the control and register it for event validation instead of having to turn off enableEventValidation.

Comment: @Moo-Juice uhhh... no it doesn't this error message is badly written. Same solution pretty much here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page . You can also see it's enabled with the call System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent in the stack trace

Comment: Instead of Button i have Used Link Button and its working now .