# Error:getting Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working with jQuery.

I am populating a Dropdownlist from $.ajax post. It all works well on the client, I see the inserted items in the dropdown. However, when I try to post the data to the server two things happen:

Error:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I don't have any idea what to do.

I can't go with `EnableEventValidation="false"` because it's skipping validation and I want to validate. What could be wrong here?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7750203/795683

Comment: thanks for reply Sain Pradeep but the proble is iam populating dropdown in page using jquery i can't post back on populating the dropdown does it make sence here i had refered it while i am populating it how can i render the method   protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer){}

Comment: Can i have any example plz @Sain Pradeep