# "Invalid postback or callback argument" - No definite reason yet - Breakpoint doesnt work too on button click code

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is how my Page headers look like :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="CategoryDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="InventoryManagementSys.CategoryDetails" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

I have simple text boxes and one radio button list in my `ContentPage`, which looks like this :

```
<div class="input-group">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-9">Height/Width Apply ?</div>
         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblYN" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
              <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
      </div>
 </div>
```

My update button looks like this :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdateDetails" CausesValidation="false"
 runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
 Text="Update Details" OnClick="btnUpdateDetails_Click" />
```

I update the details in my code behind like this :

```
protected void btnUpdateDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Category catObj = new Category();

    catObj.CategoryName = txtName.Text;
    catObj.CategoryDescription = txtDesc.Text;
    catObj.HeightWidth = rblYN.SelectedValue;
    catObj.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

    int upd_result = new CategoryLogic().Update(catObj);

    if (upd_result > 0)
    {
        catObj.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;

        int upd_date = new CategoryLogic().UpdateDate(catObj);

        if (upd_date > 0)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnUpdateDetails, btnUpdateDetails.GetType(), "key", string.Format("toastr['success']('{0} - was updated successfully!')", catObj.CategoryName), true);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnUpdateDetails, btnUpdateDetails.GetType(), "key", string.Format("toastr['error']('There was some error while updating record for - {0} - Category! Please try again!')", catObj.CategoryName), true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnUpdateDetails, btnUpdateDetails.GetType(), "key", string.Format("toastr['error']('There was some error while updating record for - {0} - Category! Please try again!')", catObj.CategoryName), true);
    }
}
```

I think my code look clean. Why is this error persistent ?  I am not doing nothing new. This problem occurs while updating details.

**EDIT:**

As the answers to similar questions mentio that , this problem may arise because of the dynamically generated controls or some client side script... But I am not creating any dynamic controls except the **`text`** of the text boxes and the `RadioButtonList` selection!

In this way my problem is different than others!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page)

Comment: @user2946329 : I have already seen these questions... But that do not answer my problem

Comment: do you have client side code?

Comment: @shreesha : nope! I have some ajax calls going on the MasterPage calling a web-service... But other than that no client side code in the ContentPage

Comment: @shreesha :  Here is the complete ASPX code : http://pastebin.com/s6yracA3 and this is the C# code : http://pastebin.com/HQVkHa28

Comment: are you selecting the listitems dynamically?or creating them dynamically?

Comment: I have created them in the aspx code . But yes I am assigning values to them from code behind dynamically.. Please check the page load event of my C# code @shreesha

Comment: I tried this too : `int selection = rblYN.SelectedIndex;

            if (selection == 0)
            {
                catObj.HeightWidth = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                catObj.HeightWidth = "No";
            }` ....... Still error

Comment: may be  issue with your master page.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo : what can be the issue but ??

Comment: like you included form tag in master page.

Comment: There is a form tag on my master page.. But that is only form tag along all my web pages

Comment: can i have a look of masterpage?

Comment: MasterPage.master : http://pastebin.com/GMgpcFbk @RojalinSahoo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87452/discussion-between-rojalin-sahoo-and-abhishek-ghosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your master page you have 2 form tag.

1. `<form ID="form1" runat="server"></form>`

2.`<form method="Post"></form>`

Omit `<form method="post">` tag from master page and add `EnableEventValidation="true"` in your content page. Your problem will resolve.

Comment: Thank you so much mam :)