# Error in selection change of item in DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

In  ASP.NET project I have to load the content( `TextBlock`,`Buttons` etc) based on item selction

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_FieldType" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_FieldType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Single Line Text" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Line Text" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Date Time" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Date Only" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Single Select" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Select" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes / No" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I faced error while changing item selection related to postback or callback:

[image]

Comment: are you dynamically adding elements in the dropdown list on client side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page)

Comment: I have controlled display of  content  by setting the visibility=true or false of items based on selection in Dropdown list. But i faced error ..

Comment: are you making any changes to the items in dropdownlist ?

Comment: @Frebin Francis i have only  changed visibility in selection change of dropdown list

Comment: @jayanta can you please retry with set enableEventValidation property to false in your page ?

Comment: @Frebin Francis enableEventValidation property to false works fine .But  is is it good to do so ??

Comment: if we want to modify the server side elements using client side scripts we need to do this.

Comment: @jayanta or you can use asp.net ajax controls and set the visibility via ajax update panels.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to achieve this with javascript.

Something like this should work:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_FieldType" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Onchange=findselected()>
<asp:ListItem Text="Single Line Text" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Line Text" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Date Time" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Date Only" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Single Select" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Select" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes / No" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function findselected() {
                var selMenu =    document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>');
                var someField = document.getElementById('<%=TB1.ClientID%>');
                var anotherField = document.getElementById('label1');
                var btnField= document.getElementById('<%=ExportBtn.ClientID%>');
                if (selMenu.value == '2' || selMenu.value =='3') {
                    someField.style.display = "none";
                    anotherField.style.display = "none";
                    btnField.style.display = "none";
                }
                else {
                    someField.style.display = "";
                    anotherField.style.display = "";
                    btnField.style.display = "";
                }
            }
 </script>
```

Hope this helps,
Apex