# Changing Text Box to List Drop down gives "Invalid postback or callback argument" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have form which was built on Asp.Net platform. This form works as expected whe we enter entry as text for both Country and State and I can submit the data to the database. Now I need to change the code with the logic to have drop down for Country and State. Example: If United States is selected it shows related states and user need to select the entry from drop down and submit the form and it should save it in database. I haven't changed anything in code behind in the working code, just adding the list drop down instead of Text entry for both Country and State. I am getting error "Invalid postback or callback argument" when I click the Submit button for submission. I have included the working code with text box entry and the change I have done by replacing with the list drop down. I have also included the error detail I am getting. Looking at other postings on stackoverflow, I added enableEventValidation="false" in .aspx page, but it didn't solve the issue. Any idea how can I resolve this?

**.aspx Code with Text box field: (This is working)**

```
<tr>
  <td><div align="right"><span class="style4">*</span> State:</div><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqstate" ControlToValidate="state" ErrorMessage="Required Field!" runat="server" /></td>
  <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" name="state" type="text" id="state" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="right"><span class="style4">*</span> Country:</div><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqcountry" ControlToValidate="country" ErrorMessage="Required Field!" runat="server" /></td>
  <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" name="country" type="text" id="country" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Changed .aspx Code with List Drop Down: (This is not working)**

```
<tr>
  <td><div align="right"><label id="stateLabel" style="display: none"><span class="style4">*</span> State:</label></div><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqstate" ControlToValidate="state" ErrorMessage="Required Field!" runat="server" /></td>
  <td><asp:ListBox name="state" id="state" style="display: none" rows="1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="right"><span class="style4">*</span> Country:</div><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqcountry" ControlToValidate="country" ErrorMessage="Required Field!" runat="server" /></td>
  <td>           
   <asp:ListBox id="country" onchange="javascript:countryChange()" rows="1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem selected="false">Select Country</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Canada</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:ListBox>       
  </td>
</tr>



<!--Country and State Change Javascript-->
<script>
function countryChange() {
    var countryState = [
        [
            'US', [
            ['', 'State/Province'],
            ['AL', 'Alabama'],
            ['AK', 'Alaska'],
            ['AZ', 'Arizona'],
            ['AR', 'Arkansas'],
  ], ],
[
            'CA', [
            ['', 'State/Province'],
            ['AB', 'Alberta'],
            ['BC', 'British Columbia'],
            ['MB', 'Manitoba'],
            ['NB', 'New Brunswick'],
  ]]
   ];

    var countryElement = document.getElementById('countryId');
    var stateElement = document.getElementById('stateId');
    var stateLabelElement = document.getElementById('stateLabel');

if (countryElement && stateElement) {
        var listOfState = [
            ['XX', 'None']
        ];

        var currentCountry = countryElement.options[countryElement.selectedIndex].value;
        for (var i = 0; i < countryState.length; i++) {
            if (currentCountry == countryState[i][0]) {
                listOfState = countryState[i][1];
            }
        }
        if (listOfstate.length < 2) 
            {
            stateElement.style.display = 'none';
            stateLabelElement.style.display = 'none';
            }
    else 
        {
        stateElement.style.display = 'inline';
        stateLabelElement.style.display = 'inline';
        }
        var selectedState;
        for (var i = 0; i < stateElement.length; i++) {
            if (stateElement.options[i].selected === true) {
                selectedState = stateElement.options[i].value;
            }     
        }
        stateElement.options.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < listOfState.length; i++) {
            stateElement.options[i] = new Option(listOfState[i][1], listOfState[i][0]);
            if (listOfState[i][0] == selectedState) {
                stateElement.options[i].selected = true;
            }    
        }      
    }
}
</script>
```

**Error I am getting:**

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: One thing I notice is that your javascript is assuming the id will match what you put for your controls. That might not be right. The clientid of a control is what I've normally seen referenced when dealing with server-side controls. Not sure if that matters here but wanted to mention it.

Comment: did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page