# Sharepoint webpart with enableEventValidation=false

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, user-controls, postback, web-parts

I have a sharepoint webpart and I use below controls:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCategory">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ddlHSESubCategory" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
```

I will be setting options later using jquery ajax call.  when page is post back, I get below error:

```
Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
```

Since I am building webpart, I can not set enableEventValidation=false since I do not have access to pages directive, and this webpart can be inserted to any page.

how do I overcome this ?

Comment: there is a post with similar problem, Does this help you ? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page)

Answer (score -2):

When you are using dropdownlist or listbox, when binding this control then you have to put this in

```
if(!IsPostBack())
{
// Your code to bind or some activity
}
```