# Issues with User Control inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I am using ASP.NET
I have created a user control that look like this:
[image]
when pressing the + : the score is raised by 0.5 and the opposite for minus.

The user control contains an update panel, and the pages itself containing the script manager.
When I put this user control in page and NOT inside repeater, this works perfect.
When I put this as part of a repeater. this not work at all.
I tried to delete all the update panels and still not working.

This is the error I'm getting

[image]

Don't know how to fix this.
This is the code of the user control:

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/229041/4753489

Answer (score 0):

Often, this error shows due to not post back:

```
If(!IsPostBack){

    // your controls code here

}
```

Or, Check is your web page not using `<form>` tag more than once:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <!-- Your user controls -->
    </form>
</form>
```

You have to use only one `<form>` tag in your page.

Or, try in your ***.aspx** page like:

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```