# Invalid postback or callback argument. AutoPostBack is set and also !Page.IsPostBack in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im getting the following error when I click on any item in my ListBox:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

However, I've set AutoPostBack="True" in my ListBox and also in my DropDownList:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Form1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Form1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="19px" Width="226px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="349px" Width="501px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:ListBox>
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I've set if (!Page.IsPostBack) in my .cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient client= new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
        public localhost.WebService1 asd = new localhost.WebService1();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                 List<string> igralci = new List<string>();
                 foreach (localhost.Igralec ig in asd.vrniVseIgralce())
                 {
                     igralci.Add(ig.id + ", " + ig.ime + ", " + ig.priimek + ", " + ig.letoRojstva + "\n");
                 }
                 ListBox1.DataSource = igralci;
                 ListBox1.DataBind();


                List<string> klubi = new List<string>();
                klubi.Add("Vsi klubi");
                foreach (localhost.Klub ig in asd.vrniVseKlube())
                {
                    klubi.Add(ig.naziv);
                }

                dropDown.DataSource = klubi;
                dropDown.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Hello!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Anyone know how to get rid of the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-page

Comment: I have already tried all the answers and I'm still getting error

Answer (score 0):

The error it self says you need to add "<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> " in page, like below :-

"   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"  EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="Form1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Form1" %>"

and the error gets sorted out.

Comment: I've tried this and error is not showing anymore, but when I add SelectedIndexChanged trigger to ListBox the trigger doesnt work because of EnableEventValidation="false"

Comment: can you put latest code for HTML as I not see any code realated to selection Index changed ?

Comment: Sure! Here you go.

Comment: still not have any thing ?

Comment: I mean you are going to put your updated code but still not post your updated code

Comment: I've already updated the code. When I change selected ListBoxItem the message "Hello" should appear

Comment: did you try and check by placing breakpoint there in ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged in server side ?